# Applying a geohash_decode function to a column in a dataframe

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, geohashing

Well, I geohash_encoded the geographical coordinates to geohashes. My aim is to calculate the distance with some level of accuracy. I am trying to geohash_decode the geohashes back to geographical coordinates but I have failed to come up with a function that can do that to a column in a dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

- you are asking about Python (apologies if this was an R, Scala or other dataframe question, but you didn't specify )
- you have a Python pandas DataFrame object `df`
- `df` has a column named `geohash` containing your geohashes
- you have the `geohash2` library installed and imported (this may work with other Geohash libraries...)
- you want to overwrite `df` with a new DataFrame containing all the old data plus the new `latitude` and `longitude` columns

The following should work:

```py
def gh_decode(hash):
    lat, lon = geohash2.decode(hash)
    return pd.Series({"latitude":lat, "longitude":lon})

df = df.join(df["geohash"].apply(gh_decode))
```